# Comparing two lists using linq to sql

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Say I have two lists:

```
List<CanidateSkill> canidateSkills;
List<JobDesiredSkill> desiredSkills;

class CanidateSkill
{
    public Guid CanidateId { get; set; }
    public Guid SkillId { get; set; }
}

class JobDesiredSkill
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public Guid SkillId { get; set; }
}
```

How do you determine if:

1. At least one item in JobDesiredSkills is contained in CandidateSkills (matched on SkillId)
2. All items in JobDesiredSkills are contained in CandidateSkills

I tried this, but get this error: Unable to create a constant value of type  Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

```
 return from candidate in _db.Candidates                           
 where (candidate.CandidateSkills.Any(c => job.JobDesiredSkills.Any(j => j.SkillId == c.SkillId))) 
 select candidate;
```

I also tried this, but Contains expects a JobDesiredSkill object, but c is a CandidateSkillObject.

```
 return from candidate in _db.Candidates                           
 where CandidateSkills.Any(c => JobDesiredSkills.Contains(c)) 
 select candidate;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two linq methods that fit your exact needs:

1. [IEnumerable.Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)
2. [IEnumerable.All()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

Edit:

You need to select a "Projection" of the "Ids" in the collection to get an enumerable collection of them, then you can use any / all on those (you can't compare complex types without an explicit comparison object).

Here is a trivial example, I hope it helps.

```
List<Guid> skills = 
    new List<Guid>( Enumerable.Range( 0, 20 ).Select( n => Guid.NewGuid() ) );

List<CanidateSkill> canidateSkills = new List<CanidateSkill>
(
    Enumerable.Range( 0, 10 ).Select( c => new CanidateSkill() { CanidateId = Guid.NewGuid(), SkillId = skills.ElementAt( c ) } )
);

List<JobDesiredSkill> desiredSkills = new List<JobDesiredSkill>
(
    Enumerable.Range( 5, 15 ).Select( d => new JobDesiredSkill() { JobId = Guid.NewGuid(), SkillId = skills.ElementAt( d ) } )
);

var anyDesiredSkills = canidateSkills.Any( c => desiredSkills.Select( ds => ds.SkillId ).Contains( c.SkillId ) ); // true
var allDesiredSkills = canidateSkills.All( c => desiredSkills.Select( ds => ds.SkillId ).Contains( c.SkillId ) ); // false
```

(Note: I also edited your question to update the sample classes used in this code, hope you don't mind.)

Comment: You can't use `All` to test if all items from one sequence are in another - you can only use `All` to test is all items in a sequence match a given predicate. I could be wrong though - example usage of 2) in this scenario?

Comment: @RPM you just have to construct the right predicate - eg `JobDesiredSkills.All(j => CandidateSkills.Contains(j))`

Comment: @RPM a.All( n => b.Contains( n ) ); ?

Comment: Lol, i've been owned, forgot about contains. Nice. :)

Comment: @RPM hah, we've all been there my friend.

Comment: @RPM that's the trouble with linq - too easy to forget whole parts of it :P

Comment: Cool thanks.  I had trouble building my expression.  I'll try using the one posted by Jon.

Comment: I'm unable to do this: JobDesiredSkills.All(j => CandidateSkills.Contains(j)) because Contains expects a CandidateSkill object, but j is an JobDesiredSkill object.  How can I get around this?  Thanks...

Comment: @Brandon: I can't do a.All(n => b.Contains(n)) because in my case, a and b are lists of different types of objects.

Comment: @Prabhu can you update the question with your code sample? I'll see if I can fix it for you.

Comment: @Brandon--thanks a lot. Will give this a try when I get home!

Comment: @Brandon--I'm getting a NotSupportedException I think due to the use of a non-scalar variable in the query.  I created a different question about this since I think it's a slightly different matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674235/referencing-non-scalar-variables-not-supported.  Your thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: @Brandon--I think I solved it by setting this to a variable outside the query and using the variable instead within the query: desiredSkills.Select( ds => ds.SkillId ).  No idea why that works though.

Comment: @Prabhu Sorry I just got this! It does look like you got everything resolved though, sorry I didn't get to answer your other question.

Comment: @Brandon--no probs, your answer got me going in the right direction...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visual Studio at handy right now but it should be something like:

1.

```
 JobDesiredSkills.Where(j=>CandidateSkills.Any(c=>c.SkillId == j.SkillId)==true).ToList().Count()>0
```

2.

```
 JobDesiredSkills.Where(j=>CandidateSkills.Where(c=>c.SkillId == j.SkillId).ToList().Count()>0).ToList().Count()==JobDesiredSkills.Count()
```

Comment: This is actually what I tried originally, but I get this error:  Unable to create a constant value of type 'JobDesiredSkill'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.