# LINQ to SQL - Filtering the dataset between two nested collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, filter

I have an MVC 3 project in Visual Studio c#.  I have a LINQ to SQL query which works fine and by following an example listed elsewhere on stackoverflow:

[Comparing two lists using linq to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657915/comparing-two-lists-using-linq-to-sql)

I have been able to successfully reduce my results where my two nested collections match. This is the bit of code that did the trick (example from the link above):

```
var anyDesiredSkills = canidateSkills.Any( c => desiredSkills.Select( ds => ds.SkillId ).Contains( c.SkillId ) );
```

I've adapted this successfully, but now I need to be able to filter records using more than one condition.  I was wondering if anyone would be able to adapt the above to show how you could include more than one condition?

To give you some background on what my goal is:

1. A search page where you can select any number of contacts
2. Each contact added to the search criteria may/may not have a 'role' assigned.  If a role is present this should be factored in to the query.
3. Results returned based on this dynamic criteria.

Thanks in advance for any and all help :O)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like:

```
var desiredSkillIds = desiredSkills.Select(_=>_.SkillId).ToList();
var matchingContacts =
  from contact in Contacts
  where contact.Role == null || desiredRoles.Contains(contact.Role)
  where contact.Skills.Any(cs=> desiredSkillIds.Contains(cs.SkillId))
  select contact;
```

Or in method-based syntax:

```
var matchingContacts = Contacts
  .Where(contact => contact.Role == null || desiredRoles.Contains(contactRole))
  .Where(contact => contact.Skills.Any(cs => desiredSkillIds.Contains(cs.SkillId)));
```

Comment: Hi, that was a big help thank you! One last question. Below is a snippet of the actual statement for the contact filter. Because I'm using nested collections I've had to build the syntax slightly different so I'm unsure where to put the || clause in. e.g. servicelist.Where(d => d.ContactSelection.Any(h => model.ContactFilter.Select( ds => ds.ContactRole).Contains(h.ContactRole))); I've tried various positions but it always gets flagged up by Visual Studio.

Comment: Figured it out, I'll post my answer below.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code I used:

servicelist = servicelist.Where(

```
                    d => d.ContactSelection.Any(
                             h => model.ContactFilter.Select(ds => ds.StaffNumber).Contains(h.StaffNumber)
                               &&
                               model.ContactFilter.Select(ds => ds.ContactRole).Contains(h.ContactRole) || model.ContactFilter.Select(ds => ds.StaffNumber).Contains(h.StaffNumber) &&  model.ContactFilter.Select(ds => ds.ContactRole).Contains("0"))
                             );
```

Note that the last filter .Contains("0) is the value of '-- select role --' which is an option injected in to the drop down.  Hope this helps anyone else!